# Starting android studio from command line

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Is there a way to start android studio at a particular path say `/path/foo` from command line, such that Android Studio assumes `/path/foo` as the project root directory. Like:

```
 android-studio /path/foo
```

Opening android studio to use current directory as project root would be something like:

```
 android-studio .
```

This could be particularly handy. I couldn't find any way in documentation on searching.

Comment: what operating system are you looking to do this on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open AndroidStudio project from command line on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363546/open-androidstudio-project-from-command-line-on-osx)

Answer (score 2):

This will open your last project rather than a specific one but it's the next best thing.

```
open -a "android studio"
```

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio now includes an option to create a launcher script. As of Giraffe 2022.3.1, go to Tools > Create Command-line Launcher...

Then enter a location for the script. If the location is on your path, you can run it from a shell session.

*Doing this requires admin, even if you enter a location that your user owns.*

[image: Tools menu, create command-line launcher]
[image: Create launcher script dialog, enter script location]