# Open AndroidStudio project from command line on OSX

Tags: macos, android-studio

I would like to open an AndroidStudio project from the command line on my Mac. Something like:

```
~ $ AndroidStudio --path ~/my_android_project
```

Is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Easiest way to use it from command line is to create a shortcut using Android Studio's built in tool:
Menu --> Tools --> Create command line launcher.

After that, just call `studio myprojectname`.

[image]

Comment: I don't know when this was added, but it's by far the best solution for the problem. It should be set as the accepted answer (even though the other answers are still correct).

Comment: This one is the simplest and best of all.

Comment: This also works when a project requires "importing" and it's cross-platform (I assume). Previously I was using "open -a" which worked somewhat but did not import our old project correctly. It was also Mac-only.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the way.

Comment: In addition to proposed solution, when applied you can also run android studio in folder where you got your project already similarly like with code like so: vscode `code .` android studio `studio .`

Comment: This method no longer works, Android Studio (JetBrains?) moved it. I did the same thing by making an alias in my bash/zsh profile: `alias studio='open -b com.google.android.studio'`

Comment: @jj. in which version are you trying? I still see the option in studio 4.2.1, and in intellij idea 2021.2.1 ultimate

Comment: @AmirUval studio "2020.3.1 Patch 3" on a Mac - the option in the menu is there, but it displays a dialog: "Launcher script creation is now managed in Toolbox App Settings. See Toolbox App announcement for more details". Coincidentally the Toolbox App doesn't have it anymore (that I can tell).

Comment: Works on 2020.3.1 Patch 4. @jj maybe try again? Also, for anyone with an issue where Android Studio opens but the file doesn't display, you may need to go in and select "Create Command-line Launcher" again, and tell it to overwrite the current file.

Answer (score 153):

how about:

`open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app /path/to/my_android_project`

For Windows user, use the following command:

`start "" "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe" "X:\path\to\my_android_project"`

Comment: Works great. I added the alias: `alias androidstudio="open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app"` so I can do e.g. `androidstudio ~/my_android_project`. Thanks

Comment: And I added the alias `alias android='open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app .'` so that I can just type `android` in any Android Studio project's directory and have it open. It's the little things! ;-)

Comment: On Windows you don't even need `start ""`, it's enough to do `"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe" "X:\path\to\my_android_project"`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I didn't add the windows part, I don't know the differences... on Mac you can execute the executable directly and give it a file as an argument, and it might work... but it isn't exactly the same as having the finder open the application with a document, idk if windows is the same or different.

Comment: even this is enough `open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

Answer (score 21):

In your `~/.bash_profile` add

```
alias AndroidStudio="open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app"
```

Then reload your terminal and you can now do

```
AndroidStudio ~/my_android_project
```

Answer (score 10):

For Mac Catalina and up, paste this line into `~/.zshrc`

```
alias asd="open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app"
```

Save then reload it `source ~/.zshrc`

Now you able to open specific android project with Android Studio from terminal.

Let's try: `asd /path/to/your/project`

Comment: Its Working.Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Typing the path to the android studio application binary, followed by a path to an android project directory works for me.

for example:

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio  ~<username>/androidprojects/AndroidAppProjectDirectory
```

Comment: This is the proper solution if you want to preserve environment variables from your shell session.

Answer (score 5):

Use below command to open your project.

`open -a Android\ Studio "Your Project Path"`

Answer (score 3):

Another way, which relying only on application bundle identifier (regardless application location on disk):

```sh
open -b com.google.android.studio /path/to/your/project
```

Comment: `Tools > Create command line launcher` no longer works. This is the only command that works for me. You can make your own alias to open it in your bash/zsh profile: `alias studio='open -b com.google.android.studio'`

Answer (score 3):

For mac users

Simply run in project directory

```
studio .
```

If you receive studio command not found

Then you need to add the following path to PATH variable as below

If you're a zsh user run this in terminal

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

Add this to the file

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS"
```

save and close file

Run this to apply previous changes in current terminal

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now try to run studio . again in project directory

Hope this help someone

Answer (score 2):

#### For Mac users:

If you are using `bach`:

- Open `Terminal` and `cd` to `~` like this: `cd ~`
- Open the `.bach_profile` file with this command: `open .bach_profile`
- Add the following line in the `.bach_profile` file:
  `alias NAMEYOUWANT="/Applications/Android\ Studio.app"` for example `alias android="/Applications/Android\ Studio.app"`
- Save file and restart Terminal.

If you are using `zsh`:

- Open `Terminal` and `cd` to `~` like this: `cd ~`
- Open the `.zshrc` file with this command: `open .zshrc`
- Add the following line in the `.zshrc` file:
  `alias NAMEYOUWANT="/Applications/Android\ Studio.app"` for example `alias android="/Applications/Android\ Studio.app"`
- Save file and restart Terminal.

You can now open a project with Android Studio using this command:
`open . -a NAMEYOUWANT` (with our example it would be: `open . -a android`)

You can follow these steps to create any alias like opening Xcode, Visual Studio or even shortcut git commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper answer. There is some permission related issue. Android studio is not picking PATH.

```
chmod +x /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv
```